# Lightest text editor with tabs?

Tags: text-editor

Which is the lightest GUI text editor in Ubuntu that supports tabbed windows? I'm looking for a Windows Notepad replacement, but with tabs support.

I have no need for syntax highlighting or any other features.

Comment: Please define "lightest"

Comment: @A.B. Should start quickly.

Comment: And what is quick? 1s, 1ms?

Answer (score 5):

Standard text editor in Ubuntu (`gedit`) supports tabs.

Answer (score 3):

**Geany**

Geany is a famous cross platform text editors and lot of Ubuntu users use it. You can install Geany from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Or run :

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

Comment: No, that is not good because of the above answer.

Comment: @ColDue96 can you explain, why this answer isn't good as the gedit answer?

Comment: Geany is based on the same engine as notepad++ in case anyone's interested.  And SciTE, and notepad2 and a bunch of others.  Geany seems to be the most well respected of those, other than maybe Notepad++ which is Windows only

Answer (score 0):

There is ubuntu alternative for notepad++

To install `notepadqq run the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:notepadqq-team/notepadqq
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install notepadqq
```